# Ajax form submit preventDefault() doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, form-submit, preventdefault

So basically i want to show a loading gif before the content of the page is shown. So i made two divs like this.

```
<div id="wait"><img src="img/loading.svg" style="width:max-width;height:50px;"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

And i added some javascript to hide the loading gif and show the content as shown below

```
 $('#content').css('display', 'none');


$(document).ready(function() { setTimeout(function() {
$('#wait').css('display', 'none');
}, 3000);

setTimeout(function() {
$('#content').load('portfolio.html');
}, 3100);});
```

Now when i do this, the form ajax shown below doesnt work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//Validate Form Start
var form = $('#form');

form.submit(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
    console.log(form.serialize());

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: form.attr("action"),
    data: form.serialize(),
    success: function(response) {
        console.log("Email Sent.");
        $('.form').html('Message Sent! Await response.');
        $('.form').attr('class', 'btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block form');
        function submitTimeout() {
            $('.form').html('Send Another Message?');
            $('.form').attr('class', 'btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block form');
        }
        setTimeout(submitTimeout, 3000);
        form.each(function(){
            this.reset();
            });
        }
    });
});
//Validate form end.});
```

It doesn't use ajax to submit the form . It uses default submission inspite of mentioning preventDefault() method. Any fixes please?

Answer (score 1):

Add `return false;` at the end of your submit function. It will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that return false on form.onsubmit event works better than e.preventDefault() for this purpose.

Like this:

```
form.onsubmit = function(evt){
    ...
    $.ajax({ ...
    ...
    // At the end of the function
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Then, probably your code has some error before return false. On chrome developer tools -> sources tab -> enable "pause on exceptions". This will highlight if any error hits on form submit before it refreshes the page.

Comment: Fixed it now  .My jumbotron is dynamically added in DOM, so i needed to use event delegation like $('#content').on('click', '.jumbotron', function() {